# IP geolocation map : API: Leaflet:Openstreetmap

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a website that is able to do an IP search and then with a marker, pinpoint the area using latitude and longitude.

ISSUES:

1. when I run the code I get this error in console ... (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ())
2. I can't figure out how to have a marker that changes with the latitude and longitude
   [enter link description here](https://github.com/sisiwhon/githubtest/blob/main/please.html)

iVE LINKED MY CODE:

this is the code that I'm having issues with
IP Adress api: https://ipfind.com
Mapping sites:
https://leafletjs.com and https://www.openstreetmap.org

Comment: Please try to post only relevant code in the answer instead of linking it, it makes it easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `/` between domain and `?ip`

`https://api.ipfind.com?ip=" + document.getElementById("in").value + "=ADD SPECIAL KEY HERE`

should be

`https://api.ipfind.com/?ip=" + document.getElementById("in").value + "=ADD SPECIAL KEY HERE`